# Replace JLabel text multiple times on JButton action

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, jlabel

When a `JButton` is clicked I need to empty the `JLabel` using `setText`. Inside `actionPerformed`, I have another Java class call.

If it returns an exception, then I have to change the label to `setText("Error occurred")`.

If it returns the result, I have to change the same label to `setText("Process completed")`.

I tried to generate an exception and it worked fine, but when I click the button again the text is not replaced with the empty string. Instead, it still shows "error occurred".

Please see the code below and let me know what I need to change.

```
btnConvert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        label1.setText("");

        if(lblSource.getText().isEmpty()) {
            label2.setText("You have missed to select!! Please select it");
        }
        else {
            label1.setText("processing... ");
            VelConverter v = new VelConverter(locations);
            String response = v.convert();
            if(response.startsWith("Exception")) {  
                //code
                label1.setText("Error Occurred");
                
            }
            else {
                //code
                label1.setText("Completed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) The problem sounds like the code is blocking the EDT. Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Both empty value and the "Processing..." message will be never displayed, since the GUI can only update after that the pending events are processed. According to your code only "Completed" and "Error occurred" are possible label values after processing. Remember that Swing is single-threaded, if you do a long processing in the ActionListener you should consider using a SwingWorker to do the heavy job.

Comment: Andrew Thompson Edited the code. I will  also check concurrency in swing

Comment: *"Edited the code."* Why are you telling me? More importantly, when can we expect to see the MRE / SSCCE?

Comment: Tip: Add @Rocco (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Glad you solved it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Rocco and Andrew Thomson. Your suggestion about concurrency made me to research on Swing worker. I just separated the threads using Swing worker and I were able to achieve my requirement.

This link made me to understand Swing worked in simple terms. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swingworker-in-java/